# Get the CMake build directory when setting a Conan package as editable

Tags: c++, cmake, conan

I'm trying to deduce the build directory of a local Conan package that's built using CMake so that I can set things like the lib and bin directories for when the package is set to editable mode.  In essence, I want to be able to do the following:

```
    def package_info(self):
        self.cpp_info.libs = [f"{self.name}"]

        # for Conan editable mode
        if not self.in_local_cache:
            self.cpp_info.includedirs = glob.glob("sources/*/include")
            self.cpp_info.libdirs = [f"{cmake_build_dir}/{self.settings.build_type}"]
            self.cpp_info.bindirs = [f"{cmake_build_dir}/{self.settings.build_type}"]
```

The problem is I don't see a way to set that `cmake_build_dir` variable other than through convention.  Internally, we are already using a convention of putting checked in code within a sources folder, which is where the CMakeLists.txt file lives, and making a `build/win` folder, which is where we run the CMake command from (`cmake ..\..\sources -A x64 -G "Visual Studio 15"` to generate a Visual Studio solution).  However, this is only a convention, and I'd like it to use the actual directory structure instead, especially since cross platform builds will necessary in the future.

I've tried printing out a few variables from an editable package to see if I can get anything useful.  `self.build_folder` seemed like the most obvious, but it's empty inside the `package_info` method.  I also tried to create a CMake object like is done in the `build` method (`cmake = CMake(self)`), but that just produced an error because `self` doesn't have the `replace` attribute either.  The best I could do is get the folder that contains the conanfile.py with `self.recipe_folder`.

Is there an easy way to get the build folder from Conan/CMake, or do I just have to force a convention on my fellow developers in order to set packages as editable?

Comment: Are you aware of the new ``layout()`` method, and helpers like ``cmake_layout()``? They should make a recipe ``editable`` out of the box, you can try with the ``conan new hello/0.1 -m=cmake_lib`` template.

Comment: @drodri I've looked at some of the documentation around that, yes.  Unfortunately, the default settings don't match our directory structure so they would have to be customized in each conanfile anyway.  Instead of "solving" the issue, I think we're just going to go with the "at least make life easier" route and create a package that we can include through `python_requires` that exposes some helper functions.

Comment: Yes, I think that is a good direction. ``cmake_layout()`` is intended to serve as an example default layout, but it is expected that many users will have different layouts, and will have to implement their own layout description. If using ``cmake`` maybe it is not that different to the provided one, and it is enough with small variations, but otherwise, writing your own, and reusing it in all your recipes via ``python_requires`` would be the recommended approach.